# Why shellcode does not work?

Tags: security, redhat, buffer-overflow, shellcode

I am trying to do a buffer flow exploit demo. I want to use shell code to overflow a stack and get a sh session. I can follow the tutorial from here http://www.shell-storm.org/papers/files/432.pdf and even produce exactly the same shellcode. But I am not able to make the shellcode run using `shellcode3.c` as in the tutorial. What I got is always "Segmentation Fault".

I am using "Red Hat Enterprise Linux AS release 4 (Nahant Update 4)".

I want to know is there anyone ever make it work using similar method? Do I need to change to other system?

Comment: When was this paper written like 1999? Well, welcome to 2011,  and none of this shit works anymore.

Comment: buffer overflow exploits still work, you just have to get around aslr and dep on todays systems. exploit-db.com has a ton of these type of exploits for todays systems

Answer (score 1):

The segmentation fault means that you did overflow the stack and trigger a crash; you need to find the correct offset for EIP and place your shellcode there. If you are confident that you are putting your shellcode in the right place, you can always use Metasploit to generate shellcode for your needs. You are also going to have to make sure you turn off the various stack overflow protections that are turned on by default in modern day Linux versions.  Google will tell you anything you need to know. Have you checked out http://www.corelan.be? It's for Windows exploit development, but it's a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

The Linux which you use is an important factor; the whole structure of the stack will be different for different os.
A good shell code must not contain Null bytes,which will stop the execution of the code in buffer.

> "\xeb\x1f\x5e\x89\x76\x08\x31\xc0\x88\x46\x07\x89\x46\x0c\xb0\x0b\x89\xf3\x8d\x4e\x08\x8d \x56\x0c\xcd\x80\x31\xdb\x89\xd8\x40\xcd\x80\xe8\xdc\xff\xff\xff/bin/sh"

Above is a good shellcode, just 46 bytes.
This site will help you to find out the structure and other informations about your Red-hat stack
Also u have to disable all types of stack protections like execstack,Stack canaries by using 'gcc -fno-stack-protector -o out test.c'

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you did overwrite the stack due to which Segmentation Fault occured. Use a debugger like gdb to find out the exact contents of the EIP register and the address of your shellcode. They should match. Try to figure out where the jump is being made and where it should be. This would give you a better idea.